# An application consuming almost 100% CPU on A SYSTEM

Tags: c#, cpu, process, cpu-usage

My application uses some webservice's and gets connectd to a server and sits on the system tray. Application just reads from 3rd part app (local) that is used to connect to the server. If it reads any inappropriate line, then fires/handles appropriate events. Thar's it. Had tested on our normal working systems and it is working fine. On my system Quad 2.66GHz and 3GB of RAM the app consumes 25 of CPU.

Recently checked on a PIV 3.0Ghz system containing 2GB of RAM system, the application consumes 98 of CPU.

What can this be ? On a better processor the app consumes almost 4 times more of CPU than mine. Why so ? What can be the reasons for the same. Any ideas to handle out the same.

Once connected, this is the code that is active A cmd is run for using 3rd party app and I use this code to read the output of the same:

```
    private void Process_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        string d = e.Data;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(d))
        {
            if (sb != null)
                sb.Append(d + "\n");
            //Console.WriteLine("LINE = " + d);
            ERROR_CODE = -1;
            if (d.IndexOf("Initialization Sequence Completed") >= 0)
            {
                connected = true;
                Console.WriteLine("********* Connected = " + connected);
                return;
            } else if (isInValidLine(d))
            {
                if (d.IndexOf("Exiting") >= 0 || d.IndexOf("The requested name is valid but does not have an IP address.") >= 0)
                {
                    if (caughtExp == false)
                    {
                        connected = false;
                        caughtExp = true;
                        errorMsg = d;
                        ERROR_CODE = ERROR_EXIT;
                        OnOpenVpnDisConnectionEvent();
                    }
                }
                else if (d.IndexOf("errno=", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > 0
                    || d.IndexOf("error:2006D080", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0
                    || d.IndexOf("code=995", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0
                    || d.IndexOf("There are no TAP-Win32 adapters on this system", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0
                    || d.IndexOf("Error opening configuration file", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0
                    || (d.IndexOf("CreateIpForwardEntry: Access is denied.", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0 
                                        && d.IndexOf("[status=5 if_index=", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
                    || d.IndexOf("CreateFile failed on TAP device") >= 0  )
                {
                    // Want to handle all and go for ReConnect, atmost possible
                    caughtExp = true;
                    connected = false;
                    errorMsg = d;
                    ERROR_CODE = ERROR_FATAL;
                    OnOpenVpnDisConnectionEvent();
                }

                return;
            }
        }
        return;
    }

    private bool isInValidLine(string line)
    {
        if (line.IndexOf("errno=", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0 
            || line.IndexOf("error:2006D080", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0
            || line.IndexOf("code=995", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0
            || line.IndexOf("There are no TAP-Win32 adapters on this system", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0
            || line.IndexOf("Error opening configuration file", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0
            || line.IndexOf("Exiting") >= 0
            || line.IndexOf("The requested name is valid but does not have an IP address.") >= 0
            || line.IndexOf("CreateFile failed on TAP device") >= 0    // && (line.IndexOf("General failure (ERROR_GEN_FAILURE) (errno=31)") >= 0) ) 
            )
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Why does it take so much of CPU on that system ?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Tried using any profiling applications perhaps Ant profiler? AQTime? SpeedTrace? Those will pin point the hot spots.

Comment: Relevant: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/12/02/499389.aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/12/03/10097861.aspx

Comment: It consumes all the available CPU in the execution thread...almost 100% for a single core, 25% for a 4 cores CPU (100% of the core where it's executing)

Comment: @Adriano, kindly refer my comment added to Doughlas. Can you help me understand and throw some light on it.

Comment: Yes, with sharing it'll decrease its usage (but different processes may run of different cores!) anyway if this is his behavior then it'll use all available CPU time. If you do not want to use all CPU time (because it slows down your system or it consumes too much battery) you may decrease process priority. (as pointed by @Douglas) it may be the result of a loop or a simply your application consumes data more slowly than their production). Try to run under profiler!

Comment: @Adriano, I got that part. The above code is for Diagnotics.Process, there is no thread running. I also realized, that I have a timer that clicks on interval of 10ms. This timer is to keep the "UpdatedLayeredWindow" refresh all time. Without this the screen gets disturbed. I don't think I can set any priority for Timer. What do you say ?

Comment: No, you can't set the priority of the System.Windows.Forms.Timer object (it has the priority of the process). The question is _do you really have to call that function so often?_

Comment: Yes, as the function manages the UpdateLayeredWindow to maintain transparent image, controls and also show the blinking cursors. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/91e5df38-09c3-4e4e-8a04-7d3396ec0f27   There is no other option lft for this. After lots of RnD, Q.Ans from experts have got this thing done so nicely.

Comment: But ya, once connected I minimize the app to sys tray and restore it back when needed. A thought - can I change the timer interval when minimized from 10 to 100 or so, and when the app is restored, change the timer interval back to 10. Can this be a good option ?

Comment: When minimized can't you disable it? Anyway I'm thinking: application is consuming 100% of one core only for make-up...I understand it's annoying to change something that works but...

Comment: I agree with you 100% and I did it and it does work on my PC very well. Hope it works on 64bit and other systems too.

Comment: @Adriano, can you add a small ans to my question, so can mark your ans as "Answer".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It consumes all the available CPU in the execution thread: almost 100% for a single core, 25% for a 4 cores CPU (100% of the core where it's executing).

As pointed by @Douglas it may be the result of a loop or a simply your application consumes data more slowly than their production).

If this is its behavior then it'll use all available CPU time. If you do not want to use all CPU time (because it slows down your system or it consumes too much battery) you may decrease process priority. You can't set the priority of the `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` object (it has the priority of the process). The question is do you really have to call that function so often? When minimized can't you disable it? Anyway I'm thinking: application is consuming 100% of one core only for make-up...I understand it's annoying to change something that works but...

Answer (score 3):

At a guess, the 25% is one complete core, and the P4 (much worse by the way - MHz is a terrible way to compare processors) is single-threaded, so it is completely busy.

You have a busy loop in your code (I suspect), so are keeping one thread of execution CPU-busy all the time.

On a multi-core system other processes will go on to other cores if they are available.

The CPU usage will continue while you have this tight loop, even if it's iterating over an empty collection of connections. Either put a sleep in it, or call the function less frequently, or do the job properly, and do a select or poll so that the OS wakes you when you have data

Comment: @Doughlas, Thanks for your info. So if some other application is kept running like this (I mean v. active), will the CPU of my app, affect - I guess it will decrease due to sharing. Or is it like each application in "Processes" have their own CPU and its usage % is shown ?

Comment: @Doughlas, When the application is disconnected from the server, its not doing anything - just logged on. The above loop is also no more active as the process has expired and turned to be null. At this stage also will it remain to 25 of CPU only or it should go down somewhere ?  On my Quad system, after disconnecting also it consumes 25 of CPU.

Comment: @Tvd The percentage will be shared, but on a multi-core system other processes will go on to other cores if they are available. The CPU usage will continue while you have this tight loop. Either put a sleep in it, or call the function less frequently, or do the job properly, and do a `select` or `poll` so that the OS wakes you when you have data.

Comment: @Doughlas, what is select or poll

Comment: @Tvd they are functions for waiting for multiple events to happen - not sure of the Windows equivalents.